# Como abrir(executar) um arquivo .bat pelo php?

Tags: php, pdf, cmd

Possuo um arquivo.bat cuja a função é enviar um arquivo.pdf para impressora. No mesmo diretório tenho meu arquivo.php. Usei a função `exec('imprimir.bat')`, e tentei o mesmo código do arquivo.bat só que usando o `system`:

`system('cmd /c cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader
AcroRd32.exe /t "D:\documento.pdf" "HP DeskJet 2130 series" "HP DeskJet 2130 
series" "USB002"')`.

E até tentei vincular JavaScript:

`<input type="button" value="imprimir" onclick="window.open('imprimir.bat')" />`

Mas nada Funcionou! A página fica num loop eterno de carregamento e não executa o comando. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se você tivesse um poquinho mais de lógica, resolveria isso fácil fácil, você já resolveu o problema? ou quer a resposta ainda?

Comment: Eu sou meio iniciante ainda @CristianMota, se vc puder me ajudar, então por favor!

Comment: Se ouver como deixar esse Batch em loop, deixe-o em loop, aguardando pela existência de um arquivo .txt. quando você quiser imprimir, faça o codigo PHP criar o arquivo .txt e quando ele existir, o Batch delete ele e em seguida faça sua impressão. é uma gambearra, mas creio que funcione. de preferência, compile esse Batch, deixando o prompt oculto, depois jogue na pasta inicializar.

Comment: @CristianMota Você poderia me explicar melhor? Me dar exemplos ou algo do tipo?